# Crop and resize an image client side and upload to Amazon S3

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Because of Heroku's ephemeral file system, I need to be able to crop and resize images on the client before uploading directly to Amazon S3.

I have been playing with different options for a while but can't see how to put it all together.

With blueimp's [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) I can successfully resize the image and upload, but I can't figure out how to combine it with a cropping functionality. Blueimp has a [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) plugin but I can't see how to combine it with the uploading.

Can anyone help? I feel like this would be helpful info for others wanting to do crop and resizing with Heroku and Amazon S3.

Comment: You should not do this client-side. Upload to Heroku, process the image, and then upload to S3.

Comment: Heroku says that the file might get purged before it gets uploaded to S3. Plus, then the client has to wait for the image to upload from Heroku to S3 without any feedback...

Comment: Don't save the file on Heroku. Process it in memory.

Comment: An alternative is doing the raw upload from the client side to S3, then notifying the back end that a new image has been uploaded and that it needs to be processed.

Comment: How do you process it in memory? With Heroku the processing would hold up the dyno. Are you suggesting delegating the image processing to a background dyno? Gets pricey...

Comment: @jsonGauten Did you find a solution for this problem??? I now hitted the same wall and planning to process the image client side....